# Can anyone tell me how to grant a same set of permissions to every file and directory inside a directory on web host?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, file-permissions

I am using a web hosting (www.hosting.co.in) and a premium linux plan, i installed a wordpress website in the public root and started making a theme, now every time i add a component a resourcem or a file or a directory i have to change permissions for every one of them is there a better way to do this ? Can i do using .htaccess or should i use any other software?

```
my current .htaccess files contents are - 
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not .htaccess problem. You probably need to set [`appropriate umask`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) on those directories.

Comment: Thanks, i googled it a bit, but i still but can not find how to do a umask on a cpanel. I tried to find the envvars file, but couldnt locate it using my file manager but couldnt find it, can you please elaborate it for a cpanel

Comment: I have never used cpanel since I always had ssh access. But most likely there will be some way to run custom unix commands from cpanel also.

Comment: You're welcome, hopefully you will find a way to run this from cpanel.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't a mod_rewrite or .htaccess issue; it's a file/folder permissions issue with wp-content or possibly all Wordpress files, depending on the host's server setup (shared or your own box, `suexec` or not; and sometimes Windows or *unix), and how you installed Wordpress.

Best thing to do is read the docs and learn how to set permissions in Cpanel or via FTP. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions :

> Typically, all files should be owned by your user (ftp) account on
>   your web server, and should be writable by that account. On shared
>   hosts, files should never be owned by the webserver process itself
>   (sometimes this is www, or apache, or nobody user).
>
> Any file that needs write access from WordPress should be owned or
>   group-owned by the user account used by the WordPress (which may be
>   different than the server account). For example, you may have a user
>   account that lets you FTP files back and forth to your server, but
>   your server itself may run using a separate user, in a separate
>   usergroup, such as dhapache or nobody. If WordPress is running as the
>   FTP account, that account needs to have write access, i.e., be the
>   owner of the files, or belong to a group that has write access. In the
>   latter case, that would mean permissions are set more permissively
>   than default (for example, 775 rather than 755 for folders, and 664
>   instead of 644).
>
> The file and folder permissions of WordPress should be the same for
>   most users, depending on the type of installation you performed and
>   the umask settings of your system environment at the time of install.